# Getting rails DB data passed to JS for dynamically creating new select menus

Tags: javascript, json, ruby-on-rails, forms, submit

I'm attempting to create a Twitter-like webpage for practice. I have a form for submitting a new "tweet" that allows for a user to optionally add a mention of another user. In this, there is a button that allows a user to add multiple mentions (via dropdown menus) whenever they click the button.

When a user selects the "Add Mention" button, new select menus should appear. I've pasted the relevant code below. My problem is I cannot access the info from a specific user. Using ruby, I would have

```
    <select name="tweet[mentioned_user_ids][]">
      <option></option>
      <% User.all.each do |user| %>
        <option value="<%= user.id %>"><%= user.username %></option>
      <% end %>
    </select>
```

but this is static for adding a single mention. One solution was to pass a parameter of User.all to the window, but isn't this bad practice, as it will expose all of the user data to the frontend? How can I best achieve this?

```js
const APIUtil = require("./api_util");

class TweetCompose {
    constructor (el) {
        this.$el = $(el);
        this.$el.submit(this.submit.bind(this))
        this.$textArea = this.$el.find("textarea")
        this.$textArea.on("input", this.updateChars.bind(this));
        this.$newMentionButton = this.$el.find(".add_mention")
        this.$newMentionButton.on("click", this.newUserSelect.bind(this))
    }

    submit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let data = this.$el.serializeJSON()
        this.clearInput();
        this.$el.find(":input").prop("disabled", true);
        APIUtil.createTweet(data).then((tweet) => this.handleSuccess(tweet));
    }

    newUserSelect(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let $selectEl = $("<select name=tweet[mentioned_user_ids][]></select>")
        this.$el.append($selectEl);
    }

    clearInput() {
        this.$el.find('[name^=tweet]').val('');
    }

    handleSuccess(tweet) {
        this.clearInput();
        console.log(tweet);
        this.$el.find(":input").prop("disabled", false);
        let ul = this.$el.data("tweets-ul");
        $(ul).prepend(`<li>${JSON.stringify(tweet)}</li>`)
    }

    updateChars() {
        let remainChar = (140 - this.$textArea.val().length);
        $(".chars-left").text(`${remainChar} characters remaining`);
    }
}

module.exports = TweetCompose;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>New Tweet!</h2>
<form class="tweet-compose" action="/tweets" method="POST" data-tweets-ul="#feed">
  <strong class="chars-left">140 characters remaining</strong>
  <input
      type="hidden"
      name="authenticity_token"
      value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>">

  <label>
    Content
    <textarea name="tweet[content]"></textarea>
  </label>
  <br>

  <label>
    Mention
    <button class="add_mention">Add Mention</button>
  </label>
  <br>

  <input type="Submit" value="Post Tweet!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this using AJAX. First, I made a route to users#index in my routes file. Then, I created an AJAX request to that data using

```
    addUserMentions: (data) => {
        return ($.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/users",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { data }
        }))
    }
```

Lastly, I pulled that data in my TweetCompose class using the following function

```
    addMention (data) {
        let mentionDrop = $('<select name="tweet[mentioned_user_ids][]"></select>')
        data.forEach(element => {
            console.log(element.id);
            mentionDrop.append(`<option value=${element.id}>${element.username}</option>`)
        });
        this.$el.append(mentionDrop)

    }
```